# How do I integrate redux-devtools with Angular?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I'm trying to use [redux-devtools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) to debug an NgRX state issue I have in an enterprise Angular (v13) web application, where a race condition causes an action to fire twice.

While trying to use the extension to debug this issue, it seems that some of the actions fired are missing from the action list. I have read about & set the history value in the extension options as seen below, with no improvement:

[image]

I noticed the red disclaimer about [setting the value as a parameter](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md) while configuring it within your code - has anyone managed to do this with an Angular application - or get around the history limiting issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I missed [this package](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools) from the NgRX team